# Laravel creating symbolic link to main public_html folder

Tags: linux

I have installed laravel in my shared hosting and everything went well except I cant make the defaukt laravel 5 page to show in my example.com/ main directory

in SSH I did this :
       ln -s /home/username/project/public /home/username/public_html

when I do :
   ls -l   I get this :
public -> /home/username/project/public/

so basically its creating a public directory , so when I do example.com/public I see the Laravel default page, how can I make it work when I go to exmaple.com to shwo that default page instead of /public?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit either your vhost configuration, or your htaccess to make it work.

For example in the vhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName yourdomain.com

        DocumentRoot /home/username/project/public

        <Directory /home/username/project/public/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Or in .htaccess something like :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Regards,

Julien

Answer (score 0):

Because `public_html` exists it is creating a symlink inside the directory, just remove `public_html` first and then create your simlink again.